# How to create a asynchronous replication of Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle

I have access to an Oracle Database and plan on manipulating the data however, I don't want to affect the database itself. So I am wondering if it is possible to create a new database from the main one that can update itself with new data whenever the main database changes while not affecting the main database? (asynchronous replication?)

Not looking for exact code but key words or topics that I should read to find out more information. Sorry I just don't know where to really start.

Not looking to make a simple copy of an Oracle Database because that data will become stale as soon as new data is uploaded to the original database.

e.g. Database 1 has employee records. I want to clone this database and call it database 2 while also making sure that anytime database 1 changes, so does database 2 but not vice versa.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen if you change data on your 'replica' database; and then the same original data is also changed on the source database? You have a data conflict - so how would you resolve that?

Comment: I want to only update the replica database with new objects if that makes any sense. I understand the conflict you’re talking about but is there a method to ONLY update the database with new objects to avoid this conflict? Basically I want to treat the main database as a Read only database since other applications rely on this database and I can’t mess with that data

Comment: I think the term I’m looking for is child-parent database replication. Child-to-parent replication works in a similar manner, but in the opposite direction. Here the data in the child replica is editable, but the data in the parent is considered read-only. If edits are performed on the data in the parent replica, the edits are overwritten if they conflict with edits applied during synchronization.  Is this possible in Oracle?

Comment: It seems like a lot of work but in theory you could configure Streams or GoldenGate to replicate data and ignore delete and update statements.  Depending on the actual business problem you are trying to solve, it may be easier to use Workspace Manager to create a separate workspace for your changes essentially turning your updates into a very, very long-running transaction.  Workspace Manager provides a variety of options to have changes in the live workspace reflect in the child workspace that you can fine-tune to your requirements.

Comment: Based on other people’s answers (Reddit) it seems like the simplest/least headache method would just to manually import new data from DB1 into DB2 as its added